# Is there a way to Embed a Power Bi report for customers without using AAD as authentication?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

Let's say I have a portal/website in which I want to embed a Power Bi report onto for strictly customers only (non-license users).

Is there a way to do this if AAD is not available?

I have checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core) and the only option specified by Microsoft is authentication via Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your Power BI Report with an embedded token in the browser side. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports-customers).
Of course in the backend, you still need to provide appId, secret, workspaceId, report id, etc to generate this embedded token.
You can build your own logic for current login user in the browser and the embedded token generate from Backend API.

Comment: Would the end-users(customers) require AAD or is AAD only used as an authentication for the application?

Comment: Hi @mdbuzzer.  In this approach, I think for end-users in the browser side, only the embedded token is needed. So, the AAD is only used  as an authentication for the Application to generate embedded token, not for the end-users.